# Is there a way for application on Windows 64 bit to execute code both under 64 bit and 32 bit emulation layer?

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, setwindowshookex

I am interested whether I can write an application which will be able to call some code without emulation layer and some code inside of 32 bit emulation layer.

The main reason for that is that I will need to use API SetWindowHook and I want to set hook both for 64 bit and 32 bit applications.

Sure, I can create 2 application (one for 32 bit and another for 64 bit) and launch them simultaneously. However, I will need more code to manage them (start, stop, upgrade and etc).

So, I am looking whether it's possible at all to have one application.

The only idea which I have is to have one application and 2 COM DLL's (32bit and 64bit) and use a surrogate process to run code of 32 bit. However, it will require some additional COM wrappers and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest reason for the emulation layer is that your 64-bit code is going to have a larger address space. Say, for example, you have data addressed at 0x12345678aa000000. If you pass that pointer straight to 32-bit code, it will get truncated to 32-bit address space. That is, to say, that the high-order 32 bits get removed. So the address to your data looks like 0x00000000aa000000 to your 32-bit code. This is clearly a completely different area and not what you intended.

Yes, it's possible. No you shouldn't do it unless you're extremely experience with x86 and x64 assembly, and have access to the 32-bit source code to ensure that it knows that its actually running in 64-bit space and also have access to 64-bit code to ensure that all of the data it passes to the 32-bit code is only in the 32-bit address range.

No, executing 32-bit code without the emulation layer is undesirable unless you are trying to make an UBER UGLY hack.

Comment: I'd like to see a concrete example of this because I don't believe it to be possible

Comment: I'll tell you what - you give me a few days, maybe a week or two, to look through my really really old projects from waaaay back when I was working with x86 inline asm in C++ and manually loading code modules, and I'll get you a concrete example with no guarantees on stability.

Comment: Would you be able to successfully call SetWindowHook as if you were a 32-bit app using this? I would've thought the OS would still consider you a 64-bit process and only let you install a 64-bit hook, though I have no idea how Wow64 really works at such a low level. You'd certainly still need a 32-bit hook DLL, so at most you'd reduce the need for the extra process (but that would still be a big win if the technique was reliable; in fact, it's the extra running process which is more annoying than the extra DLL).

Comment: I would appreciate, if you will be able to find and share information on this subject. I don't think that i will use it (based on your commend of ugliness of this hack). However, it would be nice to see how it's done.

Comment: @inetknght: you had approx. 52-53 weeks ;) ... are you going to update your question? I'm really curious, too.

Comment: @Leo: it depends on the hook (some can run without requiring a DLL, others not). But whenever is is a DLL, the docs explicitly state that this will be an issue.

Comment: @0xC0000022L ahh whoops, I kinda got distracted and lost my job the next day. Now that I'm back in the swing of things, I'll see about getting that for you.

Comment: Have you got any idea how difficult it is to read through old code written when you were drunk one night? hehe. It crashes most of the time. :(

Answer (score 5):

I cannot suggest a better way of doing it but what I can do is give you the source to a simple hook-based tool which does exactly the same kind of thing. Feel free to the bits that are useful to you:

http://www.pretentiousname.com/NoBarTab/NoBarTab_poc3.zip

(If this URL breaks in the future, just go up a level; it'd probably because I've finished it and put a real page up for the tool and its source.)

It's a VS2010 C++ project but should be easy to compile in older IDEs. (Writing this actually put me off using VS2010 any further for now, heh.)

Obviously, if you use it, please rename any window classes and binary names to avoid conflicts with my tool. (Anything with "NoBarTab" in the name.)

FWIW, this is a tool I started writing a few weeks ago but haven't got around to finishing. The hooking part is finished, though. It hooks window creation so that it can, for specific processes, remove tabs from the Windows 7 taskbar. (I hate the way that feature is used by VMware, in particular.) I was going to release the source code anyway when I finished it...

The 32/64-bit hooking part is all done. The only thing I haven't got around to is adding a config UI so you can specify which processes it should care about, but that's not important for what you are doing.

(I should say that the way I remove tabs from the Win7 taskbar is a complete hack and might break with future versions of Windows. There's no documented way to do that so I had to settle on a nasty kludge. The actual hooking code that you'd be interested in is all "proper", though.)

Also, I made it so that almost all of the real logic is within the main 64-bit exe. The 32-bit EXE just exists to install the 32-bit hook DLL and both the 32-bit and 64-bit hook DLLs just post a message to the main 64-bit exe's hidden window. Whether that is suitable for what you're doing I leave to you to decide, but I figure it probably fits with your desire to have everything in one place as much as possible.

Hope it's useful!

Comment: @Leo: posting to another window would fail for Vista and up if the process' context inside which your hook is running runs at another privilege level, will it not? Still, +1 for something in the general direction of a solution.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: The process could allow that window message through if it needed to (the API for doing so is better on Win7 than Vista, but it can be done in both). The original post didn't mention anything about any of the processes being elevated, and privilege/UI isolation is broad issue that affects any code which aims to interact with other processes in a mixture of ILs, so I don't think it's really specific to this question or this solution, but I agree that it is something that people may need to keep in mind.

Comment: @Leo: yep, I find even myself often forgetting about it, because those rules were plugged onto Win32 with Vista and sometimes one yearns for "The Olden Times (tm)" when you could do anything across process boundaries without regard for security ;)

Answer (score 3):

[SetWinEventHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373640%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is a higher-level hooking API which handles the 32-bit/64-bit stuff for you. This came up in the answers to another [question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291938/c-event-hooks) and I thought it'd be worth mentioning here in case that solved your problem. Full credit to @atzz for his answer over there.

Whether or not SetWinEventHook is as suitable to you as the lower-level [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) will depend on exactly what you're doing. (In my case, I could probably re-write the NoBarTab code in my other answer to use the more simple API. Haven't looked in detail yet, though.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your only hope is to do it through something like out-of-process COM because each process has to be all 32 bit or all 64 bit.