# calling setwindowshookex with WH_GETMESSAGE doesn't work on any process except the injector

Tags: winapi, setwindowshookex

I previously asked a question about something similar but I believe this time the circumstances are different.

I have a DLL that has standard hook, unhook and msgProc functions. I load this DLL in my main application and then call 'hook', that is below:

```
HOOKDLL_API BOOL setHook( HWND hWnd, DWORD threadID )
{

if( hWndServer != NULL )
    return FALSE;

hook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_GETMESSAGE, (HOOKPROC)msghook, hInstance, threadID );

if( hook != NULL )
{
    hWndServer = hWnd;

    ofstream logFile;
    logFile.open( "LOG.txt" );
    logFile << "Hooked for: " << hWndServer << endl;
    logFile.close();

    return TRUE;
}

return FALSE;
}
```

The problem is that if I make it global, with threadID = 0, then msgHook only and only captures the messages received by the window of the process that loaded the library and nothing else, even if it is supposed to be a global hook.

If I supply a threadID of some other window, then I don't receive messages at all.

What could perhaps be the reason for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Are you using 64-bit Windows? If so,
  your hook process and DLL must match
  the bitness of the process(es) you
  wish to hook.
- What is hInstance in your example?
  The DLL or the EXE instance? It
  should be the DLL that contains the
  msgHook function.
- What does your msgHook do? How do you
  detect whether or not it is being
  called? Note that it will be called
  within the process(es) that you hook,
  not within your own process. (So if
  you've set a breakpoint on it, it
  won't be triggered unless you attach
  the debugger to the process you've
  hooked, rather than the process that
  installed the hook.)

Comment: I see, yes my application is built for 32 and I was testing it on mspaint.exe which is I believe 64 bit. I tried it on Skype and it worked. Weird though that it worked for certain subwindows of it only. Rest is fine I believe. Though can I not capture clicks on, say system tray, because it didnt work for it.

Comment: @DD: This question & answers may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287352/is-there-a-way-for-application-on-windows-64-bit-to-execute-code-both-under-64-bi/